# Parse specified text from page with jericho html parser

Tags: java, html-parsing, jericho-html-parser

I'm having problems when retrieving specified text from page. The example I'm using is [Patent Assignee Summary](http://assignments.uspto.gov/assignments/q?db=pat&qt=asne&reel=&frame=&pat=&pub=&asnr=&asnri=&asne=sasa&asnei=&asns=)

If you go to the site, you will see that there's a "Total: 82" (this is number of hits for criterium SASA). I need to get this number. I use jericho html parser but i can't find any function for do that.

Can someone help me on this one? I REALLY need to get this number on the page.

Thanks in advance
-Sasa

Comment: Can you switch from Jericho to another lib?

Answer (score 0):

If you can switch to [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/):

```
/* Connect to URL and parse it into a 'Document' */
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://assignments.uspto.gov/assignments/q?db=pat&qt=asne&reel=&frame=&pat=&pub=&asnr=&asnri=&asne=sasa&asnei=&asns=").get();

/* Select the required tag and print the value */
System.out.println(doc.select("p.t2").first().text());
```

Done!

**Output:**

> Total: 83
>   *(Value changed on website)*

The selector explained:

```
doc.select("p.t2") // Select each 'p'-tag with 't2' attribute from document
   .first() // Get the first one (there are two on the website, but the first one is the required one)
   .text() // Get the text of this element
```

**Documentation:**

- [Cookbook (Examples)](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/)
- [Selector API](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)
- [API Documentation (JavaDoc)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/)